# How do you create a program that shuffles a list without using the "shuffle" function?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, random, shuffle

I'm creating a program that will shuffle a list of 100 random numbers, and then swap/shuffle them 1000 times, without using the "shuffle" function. The problem is, my program doesn't work correctly. The numbers are not shuffled thoroughly at all, and I can't figure out a way to use a for loop to shuffle the numbers more than 1000 times. Help would be appreciated.

```
import random
originalnum_list=[]
num_list=[]
num_list1 = []
num_list2 = []
for num in range(100):
    num_list1.append(random.randrange(0,51))

for num in range(100):
    num_list2.append(random.randrange(0,51))
originalnum_list.append(num_list1)
originalnum_list.append(num_list2)
print "The computer entered: " + str(originalnum_list)

for shuffle in range(0,1001):
    shuffle=num_list1
    num_list1=num_list2
    num_list2=shuffle
num_list.append(num_list1)
num_list.append(num_list2) 
print "The shuffeled result is: " + str(num_list)
```

Comment: Why do you not want to use the `shuffle` function?  Is this just an exercise?

Comment: What is your logic of shuffling? I cant see any randomness in shuffling elements?

Answer (score 1):

So my understanding is that you a want a program that takes a list and then randomizes the position of that list's contents, correct?

```
import random
def list_randomizer(lst):
    result = []
    while len(lst) > 0:
        index = random.randrange(0,len(lst))
        result.append(lst.pop(index))
    return result
```

This function will shuffle any list you put into it. You can easily make it shuffle as many times as you'd like via a for loop.

```
for i in range(1000):
    list = list_randomizer(list)
```

This will keep passing the updated list into the function causing it to be reshuffled 1000 times.

Answer (score 0):

This just exchanges num_list1 and num_list2

```
for shuffle in range(0,1001):
    shuffle=num_list1
    num_list1=num_list2
    num_list2=shuffle
```

If you do it an even number of times you'll end up with an identical list.

How is the shuffle *supposed* to work? Does it need to be fair?